# How to CloudDeploy an Association as an API

Tags: apifunction

A basic example for `APIFunction[]` is

```
doubled = APIFunction[{"x" -> "Real"}, #x*2&]; doubled["x"->6.5]
```

which shows the output `13.` in a notebook. When I deploy this using

```
CloudDeploy[doubled]
```

I get back a `CloudObject`.
Calling it in a browser like "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/707...?x=6.5" will return `13.` as a response.

Now I tried the same with an association, but cannot get it to work:

```
content = APIFunction[Association["lampstatus"-> "on", "temp" -> 37.2][#x]&]; 
content["x"->"lampstatus"]
```

will give the expected output `on`, but in the browser "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/707...?x=lampstatus" will not output this single value.

Thanks for any help...

Of course this gave no better results (questions/159215):

```
URLExecute[content, {"x" -> "lampstatus"}]
```

or

```
URLBuild[First@content, {"x" -> "lampstatus"}] // Echo // SystemOpen
```

Comment: Could you point me in the documentation where the format ``APIFunction[Association[...]]`` is supported? Only `list` can be given as parameters. Association is needed when you apply those parameters like `APIFunction[....][<|..|>]`.

Comment: I did not find any documentation. Trial and error (and lack of own debugging skills) led me to "APIFunction[<|...|>[#x]&]", which obviously works per se, but not inside CloudDeploy[]. Regarding your solution "APIFunction[....][<|..|>]", where should I put the pure function and the #x ?

Comment: P.S.: If I try APIFunction[{}] with an empty list, the error message says "APIFunction expects a rule, a list of rules or an association as input..." So not only ```list``` is a valid parameter...

Comment: You can find the documentation below at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/APIFunction.html. APIFunction does not use the Association as a parameter.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the hint, this does the trick: ```content = APIFunction[{"x"->"String"},<|"lampstatus"-> "on", "temp" -> 37.2|>[#x]&];```

Comment: ...as all of this will then work as expected: ```content["x"->"lampstatus"]```   ```api = CloudDeploy[content]```  ```URLExecute[api, {"x" -> "lampstatus"}]```   ```URLBuild[First@api, {"x" -> "lampstatus"}] // Echo // SystemOpen``` and in browser ```https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/853...?x=lampstatus```

Answer (score 1):

`content = APIFunction[{"x"->"String"},<|"lampstatus"-> "on", "temp" -> 37.2|>[#x]&]; CloudDeploy[content]`